# JavaScript - Why does (0 || -0) return -0

Tags: javascript

I've tested the following code `0 || -0` in the *Chrome Developer Console* and I've got back `-0` as a result and I'm trying to figure out why. This table represents results in different JS environments.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Browser                  ║ Version         ║ 0 || -0 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║Internet Explorer 11      ║ 11.3024.14393.0 ║    0    ║
║Google Chrome             ║ 75.0.3770.100   ║   -0    ║
║Mozilla Firefox (Quantum) ║ 67.0.4          ║   -0    ║
║Microsoft Edge (Chromium) ║ 77.0.197.1      ║   -0    ║
║Microsoft Edge (Chakra)   ║ 44.17763.1.0    ║    0    ║
║Node.js                   ║ 11.1.0          ║   -0    ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

My assumption is that in the first case, when the `-0` is on the right side, the result is `-0`, however when it's on the left side, the result is `0`. This leads me to believe that when `-0` is on the left side during the *binary logical OR* operation, the sign bit is discarded (for whatever reason) and the operation is performed like this `0 || 0`. While, when it's on the right side, because the `-` operator is present, it probably added a sign bit to the number, which results in the right side number having one extra bit, causing the right side value to be returned.

What's even more interesting is that when you use positive numbers, the behavior is different. Now the `-1 || 4` returns `-1`, while `4 || -1` returns `4` and `4 || -1 || 6` returns `4` (shouldn't it return `6`). Is this behavior caused by the `-` operator or is it because I'm testing this code in the developer console?

Comment: The `||` operator tests the first value and determines it is false so just returns the 2nd value without testing it.  I believe you'll find this is the case even for IE11, but it's displaying `-0` as `0`.  Both `-0` and `0` are falsey, so you're just going to the 2nd operand to `||` in both cases

Comment: `4`, `-1`, and `6` are all truthy.  It's returning the first value it tests that's truthy, which is `4`.  It's not even testing anything else.  It has absolutely nothing to do with being a positive or negative number, the only thing that matters if it's falsey or truthy.  Try this: `4 || console.log('not 4')`

Comment: The `||` operator evaluates to its right operand if its left operand is any of: `false`, `0`, `-0`, `''`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, or `document.all`; otherwise it evaluates to its left operand. Your first case has `0` as the left operand, which is in that list, so it evaluates to the right operand; your other cases all have values that aren't in the list as the left operand, so they evaluate to the left operand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the official specification, `a || b` evaluates to `a` if `a` is truthy, or `b` if `a` is falsey. `&&` works in a similar fashion - if the whole expression's value can be determined by just checking the value of the left-hand side, it will evaluate to the left-hand side, and will otherwise evaluate to the right-hand side.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description):

> Logical OR (||)
>
> `expr1 || expr2`
>
> If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2.

Because both `0` and `-0` are falsey, `0 || -0` *should* evaluate to `-0`, because the left side was falsey.

Comparing numbers *other* than `0` / `-0` will have different effects, because other non-zero numbers are not falsey (except for `NaN`).

Perhaps IE and Edge-Chakra are simply ignoring the difference between `0` and `-0`, and display `0` regardless. For example, if you type `-0` into IE's console, you get `0` as a result (**not** `-0`):

[image]

Edge does the same thing:

[image]

The difference *may* just be purely visual, though. The following snippet prints `true`, `false`, in Edge, as expected:

```js
const x = -0;
console.log(Object.is(x, -0));
console.log(Object.is(x, 0));
```

Comment: Note: "falsy" is spelled "falsy", not "falsey".

Answer (score 1):

"*binary logical OR*" may be where the assumption gets problematic: there is bitwise/binary or, `|`, looking at the digits of the binary numbers, and logical or, `||`, looking at each operand as a single true/false value, and thus they are rather different.

You have the latter one, that is why you get back one of the exact inputs and not a "combination" of them. This is especially visible with `-1`, as in two's component code it is `111...1111` ([32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) of them in case of JavaScript when bitwise operations are involved), and thus binary or-ing anything to it just reproduces `-1`. But in case of a logical or, you get back the first operand unchanged, if it is 'true-ish', or you get back the second operand, again unchanged.

(Of course the MS thing with the `-0` described in the other answer is adding some confusion for sure, but it happens before, and independently from the logical operation)